# Find the possible states to make the result of the Bitwise OR answer

Tags: python, math

For example if you have `a1 | a2 = 0011` so the possible states for a1 and a2 are => `result = [ (0000,0011) , (0001,0010) , (0001,0011) ]`
and a1 < a2.
Our numbers are not necessarily 4-bit, they can be more.

I mean, you have the answer of Bitwise OR and you are looking for all possible states for a2, a1 (in binary).

Could you help me how to find all possible states in python? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?  You’re also missing two result states 0001|0011 and 0010|0011

Comment: If your numbers `a1` and `a2` are 4 bit binary, then it might be worth brute forcing the answer.

Comment: Your question is poorly formulated. If I understand, exhaustive search is possible (just 256 combinations).

Comment: "remember a1 < a2" -- why should we remember that? Did you tell us about this constraint somewhere earlier in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, the following itertools-based solution should work:

```
from itertools import product

def or_factors(bits):
    bit_pairs = [[('0','0')] if i == '0' else [('0','1'),('1','0'),('1','1')] for i in bits]
    num_pairs = product(*bit_pairs)
    factors = []
    for pair in num_pairs:
        a = ''
        b = ''
        for s,t in pair:
            a += s
            b += t
        if a < b: factors.append((a,b))
    return factors

print(or_factors('0011'))
#[('0000', '0011'), ('0001', '0010'), ('0001', '0011'), ('0010', '0011')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The program is independent from the amount of bits of the matching result. A decimal to binary approach.

```
from itertools import combinations

def int2bin_str(n, N=4):
    return f"{int(bin(n), 2):0{N}b}"

def int2bin_str_OR(n1, n2, N=4):
    return f"{int(bin(n1), 2) | int(bin(n2), 2):0{N}b}"

res = "0011"

combs = []
N = len(res)
max_b = 2**N - 1 # maximal binary out of N-bits

for n1, n2 in combinations(range(max_b+1), r=2):
    if int2bin_str_OR(n1, n2, N=N) == res:
        combs.append((int2bin_str(n1, N=N), int2bin_str(n2, N=N)))

print(combs)
```

Notice that `combinations` returns already ordered tuples.

---

A bit computational expensive but versatile: to get the "inputs" of another *bitwise operation* just add a new function like this

```
def int2bin_str_AND(n1, n2, N=4):
    return f"{int(bin(n1), 2) & int(bin(n2), 2):0{N}b}"
```