# find x and y with the help of third number

Tags: python, binary

Suppose that I have three binary numbers, we must Or the first number(x) and the second number(y) together and make the third number(z).
I have the third number, I also have some bits of the first and second number, now I need to get the number of possible states I can make for the first and second numbers with the lowest order.
for example

`x = 0 _`  (We only know the first bit and the first bit is unknown)

`y = _ _`  (We do not know any of its bits and we have to fill them in such a way that the condition of the problem is fulfilled)

`z = 11`

if we bitwise OR operation  x and y we find z. The possible states for x , y are `[(00,11),(01,10),(01,11)]`

Note that the first bit of all states obtained for the number x is zero

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Why isn't `(01,11)` a possible state? In any event, it isn't quite a duplicate but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74239800/4996248) is fairly similar.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes yes it is possible. tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is essentially a product where at each position there are between 1 and 3 possibilities for the x and y bits in that position. You can exploit this by using `itertools.product`. First construct, for each position, a list of the possibilities for that position, and then form their product.

In the following code I am representing numbers as lists of bits, with the blanks being represented by -1:

```
from itertools import product

#states will be represented by int lists consisting of
#0,1, or -1. -1 will be the flag that the bit is undetermined

def find_states(x,y,z):
    bit_pairs = []
    for i,j,k in zip(x,y,z):
        if k == 0:
            if max(i,j) == 1: return [] #no valid states
            bit_pairs.append([(0,0)])
        else:
            if 0 <= min(i,j):
                if i == j == 0:
                    return [] #no valid states
                else:
                    bit_pairs.append([(i,j)])
            else: #a -1 is present
                match (i,j):
                    case (-1,-1):
                        bit_pairs.append([(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])
                    case (-1,0):
                        bit_pairs.append([(1,0)])
                    case (-1,1):
                        bit_pairs.append([(0,1),(1,1)])
                    case (0,-1):
                        bit_pairs.append([(0,1)])
                    case (1,-1):
                        bit_pairs.append([(1,0),(1,1)])

    states = []
    for p in product(*bit_pairs):
        #first elements of the pairs form x, the second ones form y
        states.append(([i for i,_ in p],[j for _,j in p]))
    return states
```

For example:

```
for p in find_states([1, -1, -1, 0], [-1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]): print(p)
```

Output (each row is an x,y pair):

```
([1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0])
([1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0])
([1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0])
([1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0])
```